# Addition of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that we have a vector space $V$ and the subspaces $U=\{(x,x,y,y)\in F^4:x,y\in F\}$ and $W=\{(x,x,x,y)\in F^4:x,y\in F\}$. Then how comes
$$U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in F^4:x,y,z\in F\}?$$

Comment: "Verify the following assertion" is not a question, and it is not the topic of a question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\vec u \in U $ and $ \vec w \in W$. It follows that $\vec u + \vec w \in U + W$. Now, consider any element in $U$, which means that it is of the form $(a,a,b,b)$, with  $a, b \in F$. Consider some element in $W$. It will be of the form $(c,c,c,d)$, with $c,d \in F$.

Adding the two vectors yields: 
$$\vec e = (a,a,b,b) + (c,c,c,d) = (a+c, a+c, b+c, b+d) \in U + W.$$

However, $$(a+c, a+c, b+c, b+d) = (a+c)\cdot (1,1,0,0) + (b+c)\cdot (0,0,1,0) + (b+d)\cdot (0,0,0,1).$$
That means that our vector $\vec e$ can be written as a linear combination of the  linearly independent vectors $(1,1,0,0), \, (0,0,1,0), \, (0,0,0,1)$. Thus, $U+W$ contains all the linear combinations of the $3$ above linearly independent vectors, which means  that every element in $U+W$ can be written as:
$$x(1,1,0,0) + y(0,0,1,0) + z(0,0,0,1) = (x,x,y,z), \quad x,y,z \in F.$$

I guess you are talking about vector spaces.

Comment: Yes, and thanks.  Very clearly explained.

Comment: @user256711 Glad to be able to help.